# Axis object - Auto interval error in SSRS Drill Down Report

Tags: reporting-services, axis-labels, ssrs-2017

I am having an error message in my SSRS Drill Down-Chart report:
"**Axis object - Auto interval error due to invalid point values or axis minimum/maximum**"

It displays only for the certain values in my report, but not for all of them.
Many others work just fine.
Can't figure out this problem. I'd be appreciate if someone can advice.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Searching on Internet showed me that I and many others had had the same problem!

For me, when one of the X axis values was zero, it returned the Error you mentioned .

I am wondering whether it would be a comprehensive solution, but this worked fine for me.

Just after I added a `ChartAreas`, I set The `miniumum`  values as follows.

```
    chart.ChartAreas.Add(chartArea);
    chart.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Minimum = 0;
    chart.ChartAreas[0].AxisX2.Minimum = 0;
    chart.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.Minimum = 0;
    chart.ChartAreas[0].AxisY2.Minimum = 0;
```

You can do it for `Maximum` values, too.